# Is it good practice to count on the file system as a database?

Tags: sql, file-upload, filesystems

I'm working on an ASP.net web application that uses SQL as a database back-end.  One issue that I have is that it sometimes takes a while to get my DBA to create or modify tables in the database which under no circumstance am I allowed to modify on my own.

Here is something that I do is when I expect users to upload files with their data.

Suppose the user uploads a new record for a table called `Student_Records`.  The user uploads a record with `fname` Bob and `lname` Smith.  The record is assigned primary key `123`  The user also uploads two files: `attendance_record.pdf` and `homework_record.pdf`.  Let's suppose that I have a network share: \\foo\bar where the files are saved.

One way of handling this situtation would be to have a table `Student_Records_Files` that associates the key `123` with `Bob Smith`.  However, since I have trouble getting tables created, I've gone and done something different:  When I save the files on the server, I call them `123_attendance_record.pdf` and `123_homework_record.pdf`.  That way, I can easily identify what table record each file is associated with without having to create a new SQL table.  I am, in essence, using the file system itself as a join table (Obviously, the file system is a type of database).

In my code for retrieving the files, I scan the directory \\foo\bar and look for files that begin with each primary key number from `Student_Records`.

It seems to work very well, but is it good practice?

Comment: Are the files included in the server backup with the database?

Comment: I would say that it's not a good practice... that solution won't scale very well.  Does your DBA really make it that difficult to create only one new table in the database?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using the file system to store files. It's what it is used for.

There are a few things to keep in mind though.

1. I would consider a better method of storing the files - perhaps a directory for each user, rather than simply appending the user id to the filename.
2. Ensure that the file store is resilient and backed up with the same regularity as your database. If your database is configured to give you a backup every 10 minutes, but your file store only does a backup every day (or worse week) then you might be in for a world of pain.
3. Also consider what would happen if the user uploads two documents that are the same name.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think it's a bad practice, in general, to design your architecture based on how responsive your DBA is.  Any given compromise based on this approach may or may not be a big deal, but over time it will result in a poorly designed system.

Second, making the file name this critical seems dangerous to me; there's no protection against a person or application modifying the filename without realizing its importance.

Third, one of the advantages of having a table to maintain the join between the person and the file is that you can add additional data, such as: when was the file uploaded, what is the MIME type, has the file been read by anyone through the system, is this file a newer version of a previous file, etc. etc.  Metadata can be very powerful, and the filesystem offers only limited ways to store it.

Answer (score 1):

There are really two questions here. One is, given that for administrative reasons you cannot get changes made to the database schema, is it acceptable to devise some workaround. To that I'd have to say yes. What else can you do? In theory, if it takes two weeks to get the DBA to make a schema change for you, then this two weeks should be added to any deadline that you are given. In practice, this almost never happens. I've often worked places where some paperwork or whatever required two weeks before I could even begin work, and then I'd be given two weeks and one day to do the project. Sometimes you just have to put it together with rubber bands and bandaids.

Two is, is it a good idea to build a naming convention into file names and use this to identify files and their relationship to other data. I've done this at times and it's generally worked for me, though I have a perhaps irrational emotional feeling that it's not a good idea.

On the plus side, (a) By building information into a file name, you make it easy for both the computer and a human being to identify file associations. (Human readable as long as the naming convention is straightforward enough, anyway.) (b) By eliminating the separate storage of a link, you eliminate the possibility of a bad link. A file with the appropriate name may not exist, of course, but a database record with appropriate keys may not exist, or the file reference in such a record may be null or invalid. So it seems to solve one problem there without creating any new problems.

Potential minuses are: (a) You may have characters in the key that are not legal in file names. You may be able to just strip such characters out, or this may cause duplicates. The only safe thing to do is to escape them in some way, which is a pain. (b) You may exceed the legal length of a file name. Not as much of an issue as it was in the bad old 8.3 days. (c) You can't share files. If a database record points to a file, then two db records could point to the same file. If you must make two copies of a file, not only does this waste disk space, but it also means that if the file is updated, you must be sure to update all copies. If in your application it would make no sense to share files, than this isn't an issue.

You have to manage the files in some way, but you had to do that anyway.

I really can't think of any over-riding minuses. As I say, I've done this on occassion and didn't run into any particular problems. I'm interested in seeing others' responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not good practice because you are making your working application very dependent on specific implementation details and it would make it pretty hard to work with in the future to maintain, or if other people later needed access to your code/api.

Now weather you should do this or not is a whole different question. If you are really taking that much of a performance hit and it is significantly easier to work with how you have it, then I would say go ahead and break the rules. Ideally its good to follow best practice methods, but sometimes you have to bend the rules a little to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

First, why is this a table change as opposed to a data change? Once you have the tables set up you should only need to update rows in that table every time that a user adds new files. If you have to put up with this one-time, two-week delay then bite the bullet and just get it done right.

Second, instead of trying to work around the problem why don't you try to fix the problem? Why is the process of implementing table changes so slow? Are you at least able to work on a development database (in which you have control to test and try out these changes)? Even if it's your own laptop you can at least continue on with development. Work with your manager, the DBA, and whoever else you need to, in order to improve the process. Would it help to speed things up if your scripts went through a formal testing process before you handed them off to the DBA so that he doesn't need to test the scripts, etc. himself?

Third, if this is a production database then you should probably be building in this two-week delay into your development cycle. You know that it takes two weeks for the DBA to review and implement changes in production, so make sure that if you have a deadline for releasing functionality that you have enough lead time for it.

Building this kind of "data" into a filename has inherent problems as others have pointed out. You have no relational integrity guarantees and the "data" can be changed without knowledge of the rest of the application/database.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to keep everything in the database.

Network file I/O is spotty at best. In addition, its slower than the DB I/O.

If the DBA is difficult in getting small changes into the database, you
may be dealing with:

- A political control issue. Maybe he just knows DB stuff and is threatened
  when he perceives others moving in on his turf. Whatever his reasons, you need
  to GET WORK DONE. Period.  Document all the extra time / communication / work
  you need to do for each small change and take that up with the management.
  If the first level of management is unwilling to see things your way,
  (it does not matter what their reasons are), escalate the issue
  to the next level of management. In the past, I've gotten results this way.
  It was more of a political territory problem than a technical problem.
  The DBA eventually gave up and gave me full access to the TEST system BUT
  he also stipulated that I would need to learn his testing process,
  naming convention, his DB standards and practices, his way of testing, etc.
  I was game.
  I would also need to fix any database problems arising from changes I introduced.
  This was fair and I got to wear the DBA hat in addition to the developer hat.
  I got the freedom I needed and he got one less thing to worry about.
- A process issue. Maybe the DBA needs to put every small DB change you submit
  through a gauntlet of testing and performance analysis.  Maybe he has a highly
  normalized DB schema and because he has the big picture, he needs to normalize or
  denormalize your requested DB changes to fit into the existing schema.
  Ask to work with him. Ask him for a full DB design diagram.
  Get a good sense of his DB design philosophy. Implement your DB changes with
  his DB design philosophy in mind.  Show that you understand that he's trying
  to keep the DB in good order (understand normalization, relational constraints,
  check constraints) Give him less to worry about. He needs to trust that you
  will not muck up his database.
  Accumulate all the small changes into a lengthy script and submit them to the DBA.
  This way, you won't have to wait for each small change to go through all of his
  process / testing. In addition, you're giving him a bigger picture view of your
  development planning (that is in step with his DB design philosophy) instead of
  just the play by play.

Comment: I have a DBA who doesn't even allow other programmers to list the code to various functions.